# My App Working Fine in Pakistan But Did not Work In Bahrain

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

App works fine in pakistan when i put the code the API hits and get data from backend but in
Bahrain when I put the code it continuously loading and loading

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is not very clear. Please try showing what you've tried and point out exactly what you're stuck on. What have you tried so far? Please post the relevant parts of your code where you're getting stuck. Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to  add the  header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"

Comment: My App in which i used Get Apis where is put the code 00001 then fetch the data from API releent data working fine in Pakistan but when I put same code in baharain country does not works then I use VPN its works also in Bahrain idk whats the issue

Comment: Where i will add header "ACAO"

Comment: make sure that whatever ip you are using is not blocked by baharain country.

Comment: Check if they added your server's IP address to their whitelist

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.